# move_uploaded_file function save to different directory folder problem

Tags: php

I am using move_uploaded_file function to save my file into two folders, the folders name are `uploads_meeting_document` and `uploads_filing_file`. It just can let me upload my file to this folder name `uploads_meeting_document`, it can't save to `uploads_filing_file`folder. Anyone can guide me which part I have problem in below the coding:

```html
<?php
require_once("../conf/db_conn.php");
// Getting uploaded file
$file = $_FILES["file"];


// Uploading in "uplaods" folder

$pname = date("ymdhi")."-".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
//$title_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$tname = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$uploads_dir = 'uploads_meeting_document';
    move_uploaded_file($tname, $uploads_dir.'/'.$pname);


$uploads_dir2 = 'uploads_filing_file';
    move_uploaded_file($tname, $uploads_dir2.'/'.$pname);


?>
```

Below is my file path need to save to these folders(red arrow there)
[image: Output1]

Comment: As the name `move_uploaded_file` suggests, it MOVES file from the temporary directory to target directory. When you call the same function again on the same $_FILE variable, the file has already removed from the temporary directory. You can copy file from uploads_meeting_document directory to uploads_filing_file using PHP copy function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the second move_uploaded_file does not work, because the file was already moved to /upload_meeting_document

You will need to copy your file from there:

```
...
$uploads_dir2 = 'uploads_filing_file';
copy($uploads_dir.'/'.$pname, $uploads_dir2.'/'.$pname);
```

In case this does not work, you may have insufficient permissions for the /uploads_filing_file directory. Chech its owner and permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your helping. You solve my big problem for me.